# jre7 changing app background colors

Tags: java, swing, background, look-and-feel, nimbus

i have a relatively big app written in java6, when i run it using jre7 all works fine but the components background color turns dark violet (from grey) L&F is Nimbus, does anyone experience such an issue? any hint?

Comment: never seen, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, cmopilable, just about `the components background color turns dark violet (from grey) L&F is Nimbus`

Comment: Did you set something with a *UI/UIManager class? Or swith L&Fs dynamically? When not, I am baffled, do a virus scan.